# Keeping $_POST data after submit while getting rid of index.php in redirected URL

Tags: php, post, joomla

Within a Joomla template, I'm trying to use a form (within a Joomla article to keep the template's layout) and pass the data to a processing php-file (for example to enter this data in a mysql db). No Java.
When I hit submit, I'm losing all POST information before it reaches this processing PHP file. I believe this is because Joomla has index.php entered within any URLs.

I understood that any redirects (eg. htaccess changes), clears my needed POST variables.

How can I click on submit-button, keep the POST variables and send these to the processing PHP-file?

Thanks for any help..!

I tried changing the Joomla based URL Rewriting option, but this messes up all my other URLS.
I tried the webhost redirecting tool - this works but kills all data
I tried htaccess changes, but this doesn't seem to have any effect..plus this would also kill the POST variables
I tried relative pathing, doesn't work because of the index.php mixing in anyway.

In my form-file (the actual Joomla article in the template)

´´´´

```
<form action="process.php" method="POST" /> 
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</ form>
```

´´´´

The form.php file is located in the same folder as the process.php folder.
The form-php contents' URL has also the index.php, but is functional.

In the processing code I have this:

´´´´´´´´´´

```
$table = $_POST['formID'];
    echo ($table);

   $keys = implode(", ", (array_keys($_POST)));

   $values = implode("', '", (array_values($_POST)));
```

´´´´´´´´´´

but the $table is simply empty, due to this index.php part I can't get rid of, I believe.

All this code is in a remote folder following the classical joomla folder structure for modules, so /modules/mod_xyz/tmpl/process.php

Is there a way to properly target the form action so that the index.php is not getting mixed in in any files in the above-mentioned folder? I'd like to keep the index.php in all other links, as they work, and also, I'd like to understand why this isn't working?

Thanks a lot again

Idea is just to be able to click on the submit on the form, so that it POST data can be used in the process.php file (=entering data in the mysql database).

Answer (score 0):

This question can be considered closed.